Azure Wordpress app service - MySQL flexible server - phpmyadmin - "Cannot log in to the MySQL server" error
I have spun up a fresh Azure Wordpress app service which uses MySQL flexible server.
I try to access phpmyadmin logging in with the database adming credentials recorded during creation of the app service and I recieve "Cannot log in to the MySQL server" error.
I have attempted to reset the password from the MySQL flexible server Overview menu and that did not work.
I have also re-rolled the entire resource group / app service and that did not work either.
I have been able to access phpmyadmin before on a similar app service but it seems to keep failing with this error message now.
Hoping someone can help. THanks for looking

There can be multiple causes for that error. Please see this stackoverflow post. Also check the Azure MySQL troubleshooting guide.

In MySQL Flexible Server resource < Authentication there is a default selection as Assign access to Microsoft Entra authentication.
So, that's the reason for Cannot log in to the MySQL server. change it to above marked option then you can use the MySQL server credentials and can access it.

